# Proof of $\sum_{x = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{x}$'s divergence by absurdity?

Tags: infinity, divergent-series

(From [this site](http://www.simonsingh.net/Simpsons_Mathematics/1-12-13-14-0/).)

The following argument purports to show that the series $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} \dots = 0$. It begins with the harmonic series.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum \frac{1}{x} &= \sum \left( \frac{1}{2x - 1} + \frac{1}{2x} \right)\\
&= \sum \left( \frac{2(2x - 1)}{2x(2x - 1)} + \frac{1}{2x(2x - 1)} \right)\\
&= \sum \left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2x(2x - 1)}\right)\\
&= \sum \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + \sum\left(\frac{1}{2x(2x - 1)}\right)\\
\end{aligned}
$$

So $\sum \frac{1}{x}$ equals itself plus something, which implies that the second series is $0$. Of course, this argument is false because the harmonic series diverges.

My question: suppose we didn't know the harmonic series diverged, but we did know that $\sum\left(\frac{1}{2x(2x - 1)}\right)$ converged to a nonzero value -- it is in fact $\ln{(2)}$.

Would we then be able to conclude, from the above argument, that the harmonic series diverges? That is, if we arrive at $A = A + c$, where $c$ is constant, can we conclude that $A$ is infinite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a series is [absolutely convergent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence), then any rearrangement converges to the same value. Thus, assuming that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ converges, we have absolute convergence (all the terms are positive).

Therefore all the operations made in your reasoning (grouping terms, splitting the series in two) are valid. Since you can write $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ as itself plus something positive, you get a contradiction.

Comment: So this is a valid method of proof? Do any other proofs of divergence proceed like this?

Comment: Yes, the proof is valid (as far as I can tell). The only troubling part is the rearrangement of the terms of a series, grouping and splitting, which cannot be done in general. But assuming convergence, you have, in fact, absolute convergence, and the operations you make are valid.

Answer (score 1):

$$A = A + c$$ so subtract A from both sides. $$c = 0$$ but $c$ is not $0$, it's $\ln 2$. Contradiction. $\therefore$ the harmonic series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

$$ A = A + c \\
 1 = 1 + c/A \\
 0 = c/A \text{ only if A is infinite } $$

Comment: Ah, this is a great intuition-thing! $c/A = 0$ also in the case where $c = 0$, however.